# Как получить значения json из контроллера asp.net mvc core

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

отправляю такой запрос наконтроллер:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#thermForwardStream').focusout(function () {
            var region = $('#region option:selected').text();
            var thermForwardStream = $('#thermForwardStream').val();
            var thermBackStream = $('#thermBackStream').val();
           // alert('потерял фокус' + region + thermBackStream + thermForwardStream);
            if (thermForwardStream != 0 && thermBackStream == 70) {
              //  alert('true');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { 'thermForwardStream': thermForwardStream, 'thermBackStream': thermBackStream, 'region': region },
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetDataAnnexY", "ThermLosses")',
                    success: function (data) {
                        //СОБСТВЕННО ТУТ И ВОЗНИКАЕТ ПРОБЛЕМА
                        $('#thermForwardStream').val() = data.thermForwardStream;
                        $('#thermBackStream').val() = data.thermBackStream;
                    }
                });
            }
         //   else alert('false');
       })
    });
```

В контроллере:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDataAnnexY(double thermForwardStream, double thermBackStream, string region)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ВОШЛИ В МЕТОД GetDataAnnexY");
    ThermLossesAnnexYData thermLossesAnnexYData = new ThermLossesAnnexYData();
    if (thermForwardStream == 90 && thermBackStream == 70 && region == "Брестская")
        return Json(new { thermForwardStream = 38.27, thermBackStream = 27.38 });
    return Json(new { thermForwardStream = 1, thermBackStream = 1 });
}
```

Как передать значения из контроллера в `ajax` и передать значения полям?

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что ваша проблема заключается в заполнении полей ? может быть так : $('#thermForwardStream').val( data.thermForwardStream); ? или "data" не включает в себя необходимый Вам результат ?

Comment: data не включает в себя необходимый результат, при попытке вывести data выдает что в нем находится Object object.

Comment: могу лишь посоветовать вам воспользоваться консолью отладки (например в хроме) и посмотреть структуру возвращаемого объекта )) скорее всего вы найдета нужные вам данные, но в "обёртке" )

Comment: сработало $('#thermForwardStream').val( data.thermForwardStream);, опубликуйте ваш ответ пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае дело, скорее всего, в некорректном использовании метода присвоения значения полю : .val() - возвращает значение, а .val("value1") - устанавливает.

попробуйте :

```
$('#thermForwardStream').val(data.thermForwardStream);
```